# create class instance from class name as string and pass in argument

Tags: coffeescript, marionette

From a **string** I'm trying to **instantiate a class** (my marionette view). I found a way that works but this way has a problem where I can't actually pass a parameter to the instantiated class.
It seems when I call `typeMapping[viewType]` it's actually returning me `Show.OneNode()` instead of just `Show.OneNode`

```
  class Show.TwoNode extends App.ItemView
    template: "templates/two"
  class Show.OneNode extends App.ItemView
    template: "templates/one"

  class Show.Layout extends App.Layout
    onShow: =>
         typeMapping = {
           one: Show.OneNode
           two: Show.TwoNode
         }
         viewType = "one"      
         view = new typeMapping[viewType]
           model: @model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

again, I would have rather made this a comment, but hey that's life.  Have you tried wrapping your values from your key/value pairs in quotes to force them as strings?

```
typeMapping = {
  one: "Show.OneNode",
  two: "Show.TwoNode"
}
```

Comment: if I do this I get "typeMapping[viewType] is not a function"

Comment: manually stick the parenthesis at the end of the call:  view = new typeMapping[viewType]()  that should let you pass in your param's as well (assuming it works, it's not something I have personally tried before.

Comment: unfortunately in both cases I get the same error with or without parenthesis (), if the typeMapping has them as strings.

Comment: nevermind!! my problem was completely unrelated, the above implementation actually works, it was the model I was passing that was invalid, sorry.

Comment: ok, as a different approach, Show. is static, so... how about taking that out of the typeMapping section, adding it in the view= new Show['typeMapping[viewtype]](); ? any better?

Comment: ahh! well at least you got a solution, that's what counts. sorry I couldn't be better help.